# Rotate a cube around Y axis m*360 degrees in 200 frames?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I have a cube that I would like to rotate m*360 degrees around the Y axis in 200 frames where m is an integer. So I go to frame 1 with the default cube, press <kbd>I</kbd> for *insert keyframe* and press *rotation*. Then I go to frame 200 and rotate the cube around the Y axis m*360 degrees. I know two ways to do this:

- press <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> and manually rotate it m*360 times with the mouse, click leftbutton and press <kbd>I</kbd> for *insert keyframe* and press *rotation*
- press <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> and type 'm*360', <kbd>enter</kbd>, press <kbd>I</kbd> for *insert keyframe* and press *rotation*.

However, only the former option works; the latter option will result in a rotation of 0 and result in no rotation. For small m the former manual option is okay, but for larg m the latter option would be more handy.

Answer (score 2):

You can type m*360 directly in Transform>Rotation window. This would be the easiest and most transparent way to do that.[image]